# HTML "onclick" event in JavaScript (In a table)

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, onclick, document.write

I'm trying to convert a table I've written in HTML into Javascript because I want the table to be dynamically generated (# of rows). The main issue I'm having is that the individual cells in the table are clickable and open up another html page. Unfortunately, the html "onclick" parameter doesn't work with `document.write` statements Here is an examples of a table cell in HTML:

```
<td id="r1c1" align="center" onclick="getTicket(1,'plan',1);"><script language="JavaScript">document.write(getDate(1,"plan", "r1c1")); </script></td>
```

The functions in this line are predefined and work so I'm not going to post those, but the idea is that the function **getTicket(..)** is suppose to open up another html page.

My issues is how to get the onclick to work in JavaScript. I can create the cells in Javascript using document.write commands but don't really know how to make those cells clickable to run the function **getTicket(..)**.

Comment: Don't use `document.write`. Use [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.appendChild) or jQuery or similar.

Comment: In which Browser does this not work? Your line works fine in Safari, Chrome and Firefox. Didn't test IE … And as stated before, it's good practice to use something else than `document.write`.

Comment: If you wanna generate the attribute dinamically read my answer... hope this helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your style of Javascript programming is *ancient*, to say the least. `document.write` is a function developed mainly when there were almost no common methods to generate dynamic content.

So, you should generate your elements dynamically with methods like `document.createElement`, append your content there, then attach the elements to the DOM with modern methods like `appendChild`.

Then, you can attach event listeners using something more modern than the traditional way like `onclick`, like `addEventListener`. Here's a snippet:

```
var td = document.createElement("td");
td.innerHTML = getDate(1, "plan", "r1c1");
td.addEventListener("click", function() {
    getTicket(1, 'plan', 1);
});
row.appendChild(td);
```

I supposed that `row` is the row of the table that you're generating.

Unfortunately, IE<9 uses a different method called `attachEvent`, so it'd become:

```
td.attachEvent("onclick", function() { ...
```

Comment: Ok Thanks This worked to my liking (although getting the functions to work in a for loop was another issue but I managed to solve that as well.). It seems that I have a lot to learn about JavaScript (although I still see myself as a beginner)

Comment: Don't worry, Javascript has a very good learning curve. You'll discover it by yourself in a month :)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify attributes in HTML using function [setAttribute(Attribute, Value)](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domattribute.shtml).

With this function you can generate the cell code and define dinamically the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `document.write` to add elements to your page, there are javascript functions for this:

```
var myCell = document.createElement('td');
myCell.setAttribute('id', 'r1c1');
myCell.setAttribute('align', 'center');
myCell.onclick = function () {
    getTicket(1, 'plan', 1);
};

// myRow is the 'tr' you want this 'td' to be a child of.
myRow.appendChild(myCell);
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/teH7X/1/

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below code, if that is working then let me know I will give you some better option:-

```
<script>
   document.onload = function()
   {
       document.getElementById('r1c1').onclick = function()
       {
           getTicket(1,'plan',1);
       }
   }
</script>
```

Please check and let me know.

Comment: Thanks. I sorta know this will work but one issue of mine is that because the table is dynamically allocated, I have no control on the id of the element due to the fact that I don't know how many row's there will be

Comment: you can do one more thing, keep the class name of each id same like 'tdClass' and parameter like "1,'plan',1" you can make then as data attribute like data-first="1", data-second="plan", data-third="1" and by using jquery on 'tdClass' class click even you can get the data and then you can click the appropriate event. If you want I will write code for you :) – Pushkar just now e