# Can we give mouse listener to html table cell

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I am developing one web based application using jsp,servlet in which I have reports when user clicks on any row that record should be open.
My question is can I call listener on html table? or I need to follow another way?

Comment: It is possible. Check these similar questions [q1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346436/html-onclick-event-in-javascript-in-a-table) & [q2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252233/how-can-i-add-onclick-event-to-a-table-column)

Comment: Thank u so much learningloop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a onclick on your `<td>`, so you'll get something like :

```
<td onclick="go()">test</td>
```

Maybe its a good idea if you add some of the code you already have, makes it a lot easier to help

Comment: Thank u so much for simple n easy answer.